# Is a request for job-specific interview questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, specific-question

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27709/mobile-developer-intern-interview-questions

Are requests for interview questions for specific jobs on-topic?

Is it limited only to software-related jobs, or could everyone ask for specific interview prep questions for the job they happen to be seeking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Workplace is not for software-related jobs only. Kindergarten teachers, plumbers, dentists, construction workers, and astronauts should all be welcome here. (And I'll bet some of them would have fascinating workplace questions. :-) )

That said, questions about specific jobs are off-topic, and IMO questions about job-specific interview questions are similarly off-topic.  As jmort253 notes in his answer, sometimes these can be reworked into broader questions that are on-topic, which is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

We try to put these on hold as quickly as possible, but if they're modified, they can *lead* to great questions. It's a matter of digging a little bit to get at the deeper question. In these instances, we can help by [asking clarifying questions in the comments to tease out more details](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2699/98), which hopefully would be different than merely listing possible interviewing questions.

In this case, I pointed the asker to the [Six Guidelines of a Good Subjective Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/):

> Constructive subjective questions:
>
> 1. inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
> 2. tend to have long, not short, answers.
> 3. have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.
> 4. invite sharing experiences over opinions.
> 5. insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.
> 6. are more than just mindless social fun.